# Using a service within an activity in android

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity

Is it possible to create a a service within activity (able to access all of the buttons, textviews, functions,etc.) without creating a separate service file?  I tried something like this, but it didn't launch the service. Basically, I have an app running on an activity and now I want it to run in the background, but don't want to spend too much work fixing the code.

Edit: This is the logcat error message I get from putting service instead activity.

```
08-14 10:00:25.076: V/Tagging(3122): On Create
08-14 10:00:25.076: V/Tagging(3122): Service Starting
08-14 10:00:25.086: D/ActivityManager(1580): isSketcherDisabledInCurrentTask():false, ActivityRecord{4109a2a0 com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp}
08-14 10:00:25.086: W/ActivityManager(1580): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.jimmyc.summer.wificollection/.WiFiLocationApp$MyService }: not found
```

Something like this..

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity {

  onCreate(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
    startService(intent);
  }

  public class HelloService extends Service {

    onCreate(){
    }

    onStartCommand(){
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

All you would need to do is, move the code executed by the `activity` to the `service` and call the service the way you did in the `onCreate`.

The service should be in a separate class that extends Service from the android manifest. Also this service should be mentioned in the manifest.

You can also add buttons to the service this way and make them execute functions in the service. Thus you can have a service running in the background and a UI in the activity that controls the service.

Comment: So I need to move the activity inside of the service because I tried moving the service to the activity and it didn't work? This is terribly inefficient for readability but i just need something quick.

Comment: no just the way you have written above. All your actual working code will be inside the service. And activity will just call the service.

Comment: I think I tried this already. I believe it has something to do with using HelloService.class? And this must be created in a separate file?

Comment: I notice that it calls the intent, but it never calls onCreate inside of the service

Comment: Wouldn't this involve binding?

Comment: no. a service that does some work. an activity that calls a service. two separate classes. no binding.

Comment: I thought you can't add buttons to a service. It cannot findViewById...Also what do you mean that it should extends Service "from the Android Manifest"? This is all I have added in the manifest for service . <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />

Comment: soory my mistake. what i meant was the class should extend service. and it should be added to the manifest. You can not add buttons to a service. you can add buttons to the activity. and the activity can manipulate stuff in the service.

Comment: Sorry I mean all I added to Android manifest was this. <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".HelloService"

Comment: you must have mentioned MyService somewhere. hence the error.

Comment: It's actually the MyService class everywhere in my app. It's only HelloService here as an example.

Comment: well its not able t find MyService so i guess theres en error defining the class, the file or service in the manifest

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to register your service in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I ended up binding the activity to the class, which did the trick.